# Mysql Update Table with Multiple Sub-Queries within same table

Tags: mysql

I am converting a column datetime format within the same table using multiple sub-queries. I am getting an error that my table does not exist.

Here is my query:

```
update mytable as t
set t.PO_Date = (
   select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(PO_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
   from mytable as i 
   where i.Pri_ID = (select MAX(Pri_ID) from mytable)
);
```

I have tried changing the table alias multiple times, consistently get the error that the alias `t` does not exist.

Comment: You dont need the second select,`set t.PO_Date=DATE_FORMAT... WHERE`

Comment: Change the first line to "Update mytable t" because I do not think MySQL allows for the table alias to be defined by the keyword "as".

Comment: your target is to change the format of date for all record with max `pri_id`? could you post some sample of source data?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this in the future, here is what corrected the issue.

```
update mytable as t
set t.PO_Date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(PO_Date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY t.Pri_ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```